# Is it possible to click on email link on a document and have outlook pop up instead of salesforce?

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook

Is it possible to configure salesforce so that when the user clicks on a pdf document’s “email” link it does not bring up the internal salesforce email form but rather it brings up the outlook form?  The users have salesforce for outlook installed.

Thanks in advance!

Martine

Comment: Does the Salesforce email form appear for any `mailto:` links that appear in websites? It is most likely the operating system that is deciding what to show for an email link.

Comment: I can't imagine that mailto: handling in general would have been rediected to Salesforce. I suspect that either whatever generates the PDF is generating an SFDC link, or perhaps that the PDF viewer in Salesforce munges links for internal use. But that latter explanation seems unlikely. What happens if you download the PDF and open it in your regular PDF viewer (eg, Adobe Acrobat Reader). Where does the linkgo thenk?

Comment: @ThomasTaylor I wasn't sure what the Salesforce for outlook plugin does in this area. I think you can get something for Gmail that will capture the mailto: links.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Daniel Ballinger suggested,

> You can just use an href similar to the following (example
>   `tester@test.com` email address used):
>
> `<a href="mailto:tester@test.com">tester@test.com</a>` When the user
>   clicks the link, their default email client will be opened.

[Source:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585331/how-to-open-outlook-on-click-of-email-hyperlink)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585331/how-to-open-outlook-on-click-of-email-hyperlink